# jQuery doesn't work in ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using a Worpress plugin, that removes the default prev/next navigation on my blog and adds a load more button, which loads new posts with ajax. The problem is, all the new content that is loaded with ajax ignores my jQuery code. How can I fix this?

[Link to plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-load-more-posts/)

Plugin file load-more.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).
    var pageNum = parseInt(wpLoadMorePosts.startPage) + 1;
    // The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
    var max = parseInt(wpLoadMorePosts.maxPages);
    // The link of the next page of posts.
    var nextLink = wpLoadMorePosts.nextLink;
    
    // The content selector
    var contentSelector = wpLoadMorePosts.contentSelector;
    // The post class selector
    var postClassSelector = wpLoadMorePosts.postClassSelector;
    // The post navigation selector
    var pagerSelector = wpLoadMorePosts.pagerSelector;
    // Class to assign to the load more button
    var btnClass = wpLoadMorePosts.btnClass;
    // Text to display for load more posts button
    var loadMoreText = wpLoadMorePosts.loadMoreText;
    // Text to display while posts are loading
    var loadingText = wpLoadMorePosts.loadingText;
    // Text to display when there are no more posts left to load
    var noPostsText = wpLoadMorePosts.noPostsText;
    
    /**
     * Replace the traditional navigation with the load more posts button,
     * but only if there is at least one page of new posts to load.
     */
    if(pageNum <= max) {
        // Insert the "More Posts" link.
        $(contentSelector)
            .append('<div class="wp-load-more-posts-page-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
            .append('<button id="wp-load-more-btn" class="'+ btnClass +'">'+ loadMoreText +'</button>');
            
        // Remove the traditional navigation.
        $(pagerSelector).remove();
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Load new posts when the button is clicked.
     */
    $('#wp-load-more-btn').click(function() {
    
        // Are there more posts to load?
        if(pageNum <= max) {
        
            // Show that we're working.
            $(this).text(loadingText);
            
            $('.wp-load-more-posts-page-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' ' + postClassSelector,
                function() {
                    // Update page number and nextLink.
                    pageNum++;
                    nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]*/, '/page/'+ pageNum);
                    
                    // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                    $('#wp-load-more-btn')
                        .before('<div class="wp-load-more-posts-page-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
                    
                    // Update the button message.
                    if(pageNum <= max) {
                        $('#wp-load-more-btn').text(loadMoreText);
                    } else {
                        $('#wp-load-more-btn').text(noPostsText);
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            $('#wp-load-more-btn').fadeOut();
        }   
        
        return false;
    });
});
```

Plugin file wp-load-more-posts.php:

```
<?php


if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/library/cmb2/init.php' ) ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/library/cmb2/init.php';
}

if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/wp-lmp-settings.php' ) ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/wp-lmp-settings.php';
}

function wp_load_more_posts_init() {
       global $wp_query;

       // Add code to index and archive pages.
       if( is_home() || is_archive() || is_tax() ) {    
           // Queue JS and CSS
           wp_enqueue_script(
               'wp-load-more-posts-js',
               plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'library/js/load-more.js',
               array('jquery'),
               '1.0'
           );
           
           // What page are we on?
           $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
           // How many pages of posts do we have to display?
           $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
           
           // Here we set values from the plugin options page
           $content_selector = wp_lmp_get_option( 'content_selector' );
           $post_class_selector = wp_lmp_get_option( 'post_class_selector' );
           $pager_selector = wp_lmp_get_option( 'pager_selector' );
           $btn_class = wp_lmp_get_option( 'btn_class' );
           $load_more_text = wp_lmp_get_option( 'load_more_text' );
           $loading_text = wp_lmp_get_option( 'loading_text' );
           $no_posts_text = wp_lmp_get_option( 'no_posts_text' );
           
           
           
           // Add some parameters for the JS.
           wp_localize_script(
               'wp-load-more-posts-js',
               'wpLoadMorePosts',
               array(
                   'startPage' => $paged,
                   'maxPages' => $max,
                   'nextLink' => next_posts($max, false),
                   'contentSelector' => sanitize_text_field($content_selector),
                   'postClassSelector' => sanitize_text_field($post_class_selector),
                   'pagerSelector' => sanitize_text_field($pager_selector),
                   'btnClass' => sanitize_html_class($btn_class),
                   'loadMoreText' => esc_html($load_more_text),
                   'loadingText' => esc_html($loading_text),
                   'noPostsText' => esc_html($no_posts_text)
               )
           );
       }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'wp_load_more_posts_init');

/* Adds link to Settings page on the plugins page */

add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_lmp_add_action_links' );

function wp_lmp_add_action_links ( $links ) {
       
       $mylinks = array(
          '<a href="' . admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=wp_lmp_options' ) . '">Settings</a>',
       );
       
       return array_merge( $links, $mylinks );
}

?>
```

Comment: This is likely because the ajax loaded content is loaded after your jQuery code is initialized.  Probably could modify your code to listen for the newly added content then re initialized your jQuery on those elements.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the reason why it doesn't work. Now the big question: How do I re-initalize the jQuery? I don't understand javascript a single bit. Do you have any keywords, I can type into that search field up there? ^ 
@mikerojas

Comment: _"all the new content that is loaded with ajax ignores my jQuery code"_ - ignores what, exactly? If you are talking about event handlers, then your research keyword is _event delegation_.